# use wildcards with update and replace

Tags: mysql

I have a very large MySQL table with lots of data in it, one of the fields is Invoice No, and is a number starting at 1000.001 (This is a string). I have got this from someone that left the company and they imported the data through excel and some of the numbers have come across as 1000.01 instead of 1000.010.

When I run this query in php my admin, it shows there are over 11k rows, so I can see them ok.

```
SELECT  `AnalysisID` ,  `InvoiceNo`
FROM  `STStbl000010` 
WHERE  `InvoiceNo` LIKE  '%.__'
ORDER BY  `STStbl000010`.`AnalysisID` ASC
```

So simply put I need to add a 0 (Zero) to the end of those entries.

I have tried the following, however, it just returns 0 rows effected.

Can I use wildcards like this in and Update and Replace Statement?

```
UPDATE `STStbl000010AT`
SET `InvoiceNo` = replace(`InvoiceNo`, '%.__', '%.__0')
WHERE `InvoiceNo` LIKE '%.__'
```

Thanks

Comment: just know, using a replace, will not use indexes. If it is indeed a large database, it might be very very slow :)

Comment: its probably better to use concat rather than replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in a replace, hence no matched rows.

Luckily, if you just want to add a 0, you can concatenate the string values:

```
UPDATE `STStbl000010AT`
   SET `InvoiceNo` = CONCAT(`InvoiceNo`,'0')
 WHERE `InvoiceNo` LIKE '%.__'
```